# Change xml response to array or object

Tags: php, xml, soap

I got xml responce by soap api like

```
$data = <users><user id="1028240" enabled="True" mustChangePassword="False">
<username><![CDATA[Priye1]]></username>
<firstName><![CDATA[Priye]]></firstName>
<middleName></middleName>
<lastName><![CDATA[Priye]]></lastName>
<email></email>
<company></company>
</users>
```

When i convert $data into simple xml object by

```
$array = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

i got object but object does not contain any value.

After converting object as follow

[users] => Array
            (
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1028240
                                        [enabled] => True
                                        [mustChangePassword] => False
                                    )

```
                            [username] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [firstName] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [middleName] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [lastName] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [email] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [company] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [city] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [province] => Array
                                (
                                )
}
```

}

Comment: Could you dump the object and add that to the question?

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused: 1. the first and the second version of the xml response you posted differ. 2. the output you posted is _not_ empty. So what is the question here?

Comment: The formatting of this question could be improved.

Comment: @arkascha you can see in question in xml response username and firstname is not empty but after converting in object username and first name is empty.

Comment: Hm, so _that_ us your actual issue... Why don't you say so in the question? I updated my question below to also output that CDATA stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `xml` input is invalid. In such case, if you do not any error checking and do not look at the log files where errors are shown, then you might have difficulties to see that...

Here is an example with *fixed* content:

```
<?php

$data  = <<<EOT
<users>
  <user id="1028240" enabled="True" mustChangePassword="False">
    <username><![CDATA[Priye1]]></username>
    <firstName><![CDATA[Priye]]></firstName>
    <middleName></middleName>
    <lastName><![CDATA[Priye]]></lastName>
    <email></email>
    <company></company>
  </user>
</users>
EOT;

print_r(simplexml_load_string($data, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA));
```

Note the added `</user>` towards the end which closes the `user` tag opened in the second line. Without that fix you get this warning on CLI or inside your log error log file: `PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : expected '>'`.

Also you have to tell the xml parser that is should access and interpret the contained `CDATA` content, if you want to. That is due to the fact that such data is not really considered to be part of the xml document itself. You can do that by using the flag `LIBXML_NOCDATA` as shown in the final `print_r()` call.

The output of that script is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [user] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1028240
                [enabled] => True
                [mustChangePassword] => False
            )

        [username] => Priye1
        [firstName] => Priye
        [middleName] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [lastName] => Priye
        [email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [company] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Glad I could help :-) Maybe you want to upvote or accept my answer :-)